How can I get SymbolTable of an ApexTrigger in production env
I'm trying to work with the SymbolTable via the Tooling API (I'm calling it from outside the org via SOAP / Oauth).
I can get the SymbolTable for an ApexClass without issue.
(It's a field directly on the ApexClass type in the tooling api).
However, I'm not able to get the SymbolTable for an ApexTrigger, as it's not a field directly on the ApexTrigger type.
I do understand that it's on the ApexTriggerMember and I can use the ApexTrigger to create an ApexTriggerMember...however I'm still running into issues.
The problem is that when I go through the process:

get ApexTrigger
MetadataContainer (set content to ApexTrigger)
AsyncRequest (isCheckOnly = true)

I get an error no matter what I do saying something like "can't edit metadata in production".  This error makes sense but in fact I'm NOT editing the metadata because of the "isCheckOnly = true".
So, my question is:  is it only possible to create a ApexTriggerMember with the SymbolTable populated in a SANDBOX?  Or is there someway to do this in Production that i'm missing.
Thanks!

Does this Q&A help?

Thank you @PhilW, but I believe this other answer from 2015 is inaccurate.  If it were true that it's NOT possible to create/update apex via the API, tools like sfdx inside vscode would not work on code (they do).  In addition, i've successfully compiled an apextriggermember in a sandbox via the API.  So, I'm still left wondering...can I get the symboltable from an ApexTrigger in a Production env?
